# 1 Button with 4 actions, can I sort the actions in a specific order?

Tags: ios, sorting, button, action

In my code are 1 Button with 7 IBActions.
The button start a variety of random numbers and arithmetic operations.

And now my problem: How can I say if I Klick the Button, start with:

```
- (IBAction)Zufallszahl1:(id)sender
```

then

```
- (IBAction)Zufallszahl2:(id)sender
```

then
etc...

I can't find a solution for that.

Comment: create an integer variable which tracks the random number and increases on every touch and switch over that variable to determine which code to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add 7 IBActions to a button. They will all fire every time the button is pressed.

If you want the button to do something randomly then have one action that does something like this...

```
- (IBAction)randomButtonEvent
{
    // if you want random then...
    NSInteger methodNumber = arc4random_uniform(7);

    // if you want to increment each time then have a property methodNumber
    self.methodNumber += 1;
    if (self.methodNumber == 7) {
        self.methodNumber = 0;
    }

    switch methodNumber { // or self.methodNumber
        case 0:
            // do your first action
            break;
        case 1:
            // do your second action
            break;
        case 2:
            // do your third action
            break;
        // you get the picture
    }
}
```

This will have one button event that runs one of seven methods randomly.